# Wireless Issues on Toshiba C855D Satellite

Tags: wireless, network-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Toshiba Satellite C850, Wlan, rtl8188ce not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192873/toshiba-satellite-c850-wlan-rtl8188ce-not-working)

I just bought a Toshiba C855D satellite yesterday and installed 12.04 this morning without a problem.  on the first boot up, I had no issues with wireless at all until I installed updates and restarted my computer.  At this point, even after disabling and reenabling networking, I am not being shown any wireless connections that are definitely in range.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

A quick update, I just plugged in an Ethernet cable and am getting a different problem with that. The symbol on the top seems to be indicating that it is searching for a connection as a notification pops up telling me that the wireless network is now disconnected.  It is doing this pretty much endlessly.

Results of:

lspci -nnk etc.

```
    Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8211]
Kernel modules: rtl8192ce
    06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
```

ifconfig -a

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:8c:fa:33:7f:ac  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
              Interrupt:41 Base address:0xe000 

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
              RX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:56 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
              RX bytes:3344 (3.3 KB)  TX bytes:3344 (3.3 KB)
```

Comment: Alright, I reverted back to an older kernel and the problem went away. Though I would still like to fix this so I don't have to go through the GRUB thing on startup every time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please share more about your hardware. We can't look in your laptop and the laptop model isn't really relevant as we need specific information on your wireless adapter. Could you include the output of the following command being run from a terminal? `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(network|wireless)"` and `ifconfig -a`.

Comment: Is it still useful to post these after I revert to an older kernel? I can't post it being run without the fix as I can't get to the internet while the problem is occurring.

Comment: Save the output to a file on your disk and post it booting from the older kernel later. In case the output is different, then post both.

Comment: Thanks...Both laptops that I have owned (this one included) have had wireless problems on Linux. The first one had a problem with the wireless card specific to my brand of laptop, and I guess this one is similar, but the fix isn't exactly as easy.  I'll try this tomorrow and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with my wireless after updates, it was a compaq laptop, and a broadcom wifi adapter, the menu kept saying Wireless is disabled by a hardware switch, and the only wireless switch did not work in ubuntu.

back the the point i fixed it by running these into a terminal:

sudo rmmod -f ath5k

sudo rfkill unblock all

sudo modprobe ath5k

### Original Post

Originally Posted by louisgonick View Post
i have natty dualbooting with windows on the same laptop. This commands turn my card on. Apparently ubuntu does not work with this card.
sudo rmmod -f ath5k
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe ath5k

hope this helped

Comment: After running the first command I received 'ERROR: Removing 'ath5k': No such file or directory' The problem is still persisting unfortunately.

Comment: OP has different hardware probably. `ath5k` only applies to certain Atheros based wireless chipsets.